# replace heading "Register" to "Signup"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i would like to replace heading "Register" to "Signup"

[image: i would like to replace heading "Register" to "Signup"]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to change the text. It uses the `get_text`filter to change all available translatable strings. Tested and it Works.

```
function custom_wc_translations( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ($translated_text) {
      case 'Register' :
        $translated_text = __('Sign Up', 'Domain');
        break;
    }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_wc_translations', 20, 3 );
```

Comment: this assumes that the text "Register" was not hardcoded...